# Count number of distinct items in a list without using a hash table

Tags: python, list, distinct

Say I have a list (not necessarily sorted):

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]
```

I need a function that returns count of unique elements in a list, in this case `10`.

I am not allowed to use `dict` or `set`.

I thought about doing something like:

```
num = len(lst)
for e in lst:
    for i in lst:
        if e == i:
           num -= 1
```

But clearly, it does not work. Thanks!

Comment: which question is the same as this one?

Comment: Can you provide the output that you expect?

Comment: I am expecting 10 but I cannot use set. It has to use == and nothing else. That's the catch.

Comment: So you need to count number of unique values and you know that the list is sorted?

Comment: Sorted or not isn't relevant.

Comment: Are you allowed to use sort?

Comment: Sure, I guess... But I'm not allowed to use "set" though; this is just an example. I'm actually handling class instances, and I keep encountering errors that they are unhashable if I use a set.

Comment: I voted to reopen because `OP` cannot use `set`, and all the top voted answers use `set`. I believe this is a different question, and answers to that question do not answer this question.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I believe the title of this question is misleading, but if it is changed to, say: `Count number of distinct items in a list without using a hash table.`, it will have make it clear that this question is different from the one you marked it as duplicate of.

Comment: @Akavall the requirements exclude using a dictionary, not a set. Using `len()` on the result of `set()` is a very small step to make from the duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, The OP is not allowed to use `set` either, in the comments the OP says" `But I'm not allowed to use "set".`

Comment: @Akavall then by all means improve the question. Edit it, clean it up, incorporate those details in the post. Editing will put it in the reopen queue, a good edit can easily lead to a reopen that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Any solution that does a double nested loop over a list runs in `O(n^2)` time, the following runs in `O(n log(n))` time. Though there might be a way to come with `O(n)` time solution without using a hash table, I don't see it.

```
def count_number_unique(my_list):
    prev = None
    unique_count = 0
    for ele in sorted(my_list):
        if ele != prev:
            unique_count += 1
        prev = ele
    return unique_count
```

Result:

```
In [20]: lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]

In [21]: count_number_unique(lst)
Out[21]: 10

In [22]: count_number_unique([1,2,1,9,1,2])
Out[22]: 3
```

Comment: `This function should return: 10 `